# Prove $\sum 3^k = O(3^n)$

Tags: proof-writing, notation, induction, upper-lower-bounds

> Prove $\sum_{k=0}^n 3^k = O(3^n)$.

Below there is a picture from my text that contains the proof. My question pertains to the notation and/or assumptions in the proof. I don't need help with basic induction, below you'll see I'm not exactly sure what I'm confused about, it may be notation or possibly something quantifier related.

---

The author's explanation is giving me a bit of confusion near the end of the induction step when they require that

$$\left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{c}\right) \leq 1 \tag{A}$$

I'm not sure why the constant being less than $1$ is necessary. The way I was thinking of it (maybe my definition of big O notation is off) is that in our induction we should be verifying that

$$\text{if} \quad \sum_{k=0}^n{3^k} \leq c_1 3^n \quad \text{then} \quad \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{3^k} \leq c_2 3^{n+1} \tag{B}$$

for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. If that's a valid induction approach then (by hijacking the author's proof)

$$\cdots \leq c_13^n + 3^{n+1} = \left(\frac{c_1}{3} + 1\right)3^{n+1}= c_23^{n+1} \tag{C}$$

Which would complete the proof.

[image]

T

Comment: The author’s proof shows that there is one $c$ that works for every $n$ (namely every $c > 3/2$). If you allow $c$ to change in the inductive step, you’re not proving anything interesting at all: for every function $f$ with $f(n) > 0$, you can always find $c_n$ with $\sum_{k=0}^n 3^k \leq c_n f(n)$. So you would get that the series is in $O(1/n)$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Geometric Series Theorem:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n 3^k = {3^{n+1} - 1 \over 2} = (3/2)3^{n} - 1/2 = O(3^n)..$$